# using a wildcard to prevent subtotal line from being filtered and copied excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, filtering, copy-paste

I have a situation where I have a list of salespeople that gets filtered and moves all that filtered data to it's own spreadsheet. The problem that I am having is the macro is also filtering the subtotal line so its creating a sheet with no data and it's also creating a situation where the sheet is so large I cant save the file.

I wrote some code that i thought would prevent any worksheet starting with "Sheet" to not get filtered, but I don't know how to use a wildcard in a string. Need a wildcard since the "Sheet #" is different depending on the month.

```
Dim Sht As Worksheet
        Dim Rng As Range
        Dim List As Collection
        Dim varValue As Variant
        Dim E As Long

    '   // Set your Sheet name
        Set Sht = Application.ActiveSheet

    '   // set your auto-filter,  A6
        With Sht.Range("A2")
            .AutoFilter
        End With

    '   // Set your agent Column range # (2) that you want to filter it
        Set Rng = Range(Sht.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(22).Address)


ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add 
Key:=Range _
         ("V:V"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, 
DataOption:= _
            xlSortTextAsNumbers
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With

    '   // Create a new Collection Object
        Set List = New Collection

    '   // Fill Collection with Unique Values
        On Error Resume Next
        For E = 2 To Rng.Rows.Count
            List.Add Rng.Cells(E, 1), CStr(Rng.Cells(E, 1))
        Next E

    '   // Start looping in through the collection Values
        For Each varValue In List


    '       // Filter the Autofilter to macth the current Value
            'Rng.AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:=varValue, _
             '   Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>"

            Rng.AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:="<>Sheet*", _
                Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=varValue

    '       // Copy the AutoFiltered Range to new Workbook
            'If List = (Blanks) Then
            Sht.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
```

The Criteria1:="<>Sheet*" code is what I tried to do and the code above is what is was before. So my question is what can be done to prevent to the subtotal row sheet from being created?

[image: Example of how the first tab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after playing with the code for awhile I realized that using a wildcard for "Sheet*" wouldn't work since all the filtered results started with "Sheet" in the first place. But by adding

`If varValue <> "" Then` (which states that if the filtered result isn't blank than continue code) after `Rng.AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:="<>Sheet*", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=varValue`

it fixed the issue. Now the code skips the subtotal line successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the sheet name to the autofilter criteria. Just check the sheet name before you autofilter at all.

```
If Not ActiveSheet.Name Like "Sheet*" Then
    'Do whatever you need to do
End If
```

On the other hand, you can remove the `Not` keyword if you wanted to include sheet names starting with sheet:

```
If ActiveSheet.Name Like "Sheet*" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Append a timestamp to your sheetname string. The basic idea is to use the "time" function, i.e. time (now), where time can be extracted as `yy,mm,dd,hh,ss`. Separately define variables strings to store each of the desired time components. Then, create a name like `sheetname= myname string+my dd+ my hh....` I think it can become problematic if you try to add the time results directly to your sheetname string, so save the time result first, then combine strings.

I like to start my project by setting up my workbook with `sheets(1).name ="blank"`. Hide it, unhide it, and copy it perpetually.
Good luck.